# Where are all of the memory cards located for the Memory to Spare achievement ?

Tags: far-cry-3

How many memory cards are there ? Where are they located ?

Comment: As stated in the answer below, there are 20. Most of them can be found in the shops you get access to when you take over an outpost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 20 memory cards in total.
You can buy a map with their location at the weapons dealer.
You will be able to apply a filter for the memory cards specifically.